# composer network start returns nothing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a business network archive : bank_network.bna

In order to deploy the bna, I first executed :

```
composer network install -a bank_network.bna -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1
```

And it seemed to work fine.
But when executing the composer network start command I only get a version number as output :

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n bank_network -v 0.0.1-deploy.1 -A admin -S adminpw
v0.19.12
```

And when displaying the running docker container nothing happened.
Has anyone already encountered such an error? Documentation is rather light...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is you are specifying `-v` (ie lower case v) to provide the network Version value, but `-v` means give me the version of the CLI being used which is why you get `0.19.12`.

to be safe, specify the full parameter of `--networkVersion`, but the short alternative is `-V` (ie capital V).

`composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n bank_network --networkVersion 0.0.1-deploy.1 -A admin -S adminpw`